# Use pgfplots and a custom length to define global width when inputing the plot

Tags: pgfplots, lengths, standalone

I'm trying to set the width for all my plots, that are defined in other files and imported into the main document, using a custom width, `\sz`. I'm trying to set this length because I want to change it for one or two columns. Like in this example, `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newlength{\sz}
\setlength{\sz}{0.5\linewidth}
\pgfplotsset{width=\sz,compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\input{test}
\end{document}
```

`test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x tick label style={
/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ylabel=Population,
enlargelimits=0.05,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar interval=0.7,
cycle list name=color list
]
\addplot
coordinates {(1930,50e6) (1940,33e6)
(1950,40e6) (1960,50e6) (1970,70e6)};
\addplot
coordinates {(1930,38e6) (1940,42e6)
(1950,43e6) (1960,45e6) (1970,65e6)};
\addplot
coordinates {(1930,15e6) (1940,12e6)
(1950,13e6) (1960,25e6) (1970,35e6)};
\addplot
coordinates {(1930,15e6) (1940,12e6)
(1950,13e6) (1960,25e6) (1970,35e6)};

\legend{Far,Near,Here,There}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, when I'm compiling it, the length of `\sz` is reset to zero. And I get the error: `Error: Plot width '0.0pt' is too small.` Is there any way of setting the length so that the figure in the other file is able to 'see' it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you use the `minimal` documentclass, which doesn't define `\linewidth`. If you use a proper class, like `article`, your setup works.

Comment: Thanks, my bad. Actually, I was using a different class; but for the example I decided to use a minimal to reproduce the error. However, your answer give me the hint to why it wasn't working. :)